# CountIf with a multiplier

Tags: google-sheets

say I have the following table

```
1 apple
2 banana
2 apple
3 banana
```

With COUNTIF(B1:B4;"banana") I would get 2, but I'm searching for a formular that respects the mulitplier to get 5 as result. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sum if:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B4;"banana";A1:A4)
```

First range to search

Seccond the search item

Third The range for the sum